# Where does Windows Vista's Notes gadget store your notes?

Tags: windows-vista, sync

I like to use the default notes gadget in Windows Vista, and I want to synchronize my notes between my PC and my laptop. I'm going to use Dropbox, so I just need to know where does the gadget store my notes. I looked inside the Appdata folder and couldn't find the actual notes (only configuration files). Where are they? They have to be stored somewhere, since they are saved even if you close the sidebar.

Comment: Sorry, you might have been notified of an answer--I wasn't reading carefully and thought you were talking about the Notes application in Windows 7 and was assuming that was in Vista as well, and as such, I deleted my answer.

Comment: Really, no one? Man, what's wrong with this gadget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sidebargadfetdevelopment/thread/3a375b67-02ec-4e60-aad3-2ba406daafcb), it's in

```
%localappdata%\microsoft\windows sidebar\settings.ini
```

Comment: Yep, there it is. Wonder why it's not inside the gadget's own folder. Thanks